# Query text for two expressions within distance of n words

Tags: mysql, select

I'm looking for a way to query a column in a MySQL-database containing text for cases where two expressions occures within a distance of *n* words or characters. For example: "sed" within 3 words of "eirmod" in the following sentences.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, **sed** diam
>   nonumy **eirmod** tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
>   erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
>   et ea rebum.

I couldn't find a way to include it as a condition in the `select` and `like` command.

```
SELECT * FROM database as db
WHERE db.text like '%sed%' AND db.text like '%eirmod%'
```

Is there a way to do it? Or is a complete different approach necessary? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RLIKE` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE text RLIKE 'sed ([^ ]* ){0,3}eirmod'
```

If you want to find `sed` and `eirmod` within 3 words of each other in any order, then you can expand the regex with an alternation:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE text RLIKE 'sed ([^ ]* ){0,3}eirmod|eirmod ([^ ]* ){0,3}sed'
```

Comment: Seems to work perfect. Thank you! Just one question to understand how the `rlike` command works: What does `([^ ]* ){0,10}` exactly mean?

Comment: `([^ ]* )`{0,3} means any _non_ space character followed by a single space, that entire quantity occurring between 0 and three times.  This is checking for up to three words in between `sed` and `eirmod`.

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with regex

```
select * from table
where regexp '^sed[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]]+[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]]+
[[:blank:]]eirmod'
```